# Splitting data before modeling with LightGBM

Tags: data-science, lightgbm

I am forecasting over 2000 time series using LightGBM, they contain data that have high and low variance/ differing patterns. I'm doing one model recursively forecasting 12 steps into the future. A colleague expressed his desire to see them be more expressive with the time series that aren't highly irregular as most of them tend to flatten out over time.

After doing some digging I noticed on the M5 Kaggle competition (a forecasting situation very similar to mine) the winner used lightGBM but split the data by store, item etc before doing the modeling.

My question is does LightGBM handle categorical data well in regression for multiple types of timeseries, if so why would the winner split his data beforehand? The categories I'm working with are similar to 'product' and 'store' and time features. Do I need to split my data into similar time series then train multiple models or is there something else I can try?